# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'ERC721NonexistentToken(1)'

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqy9S.png)this is my Escrow.sol.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

interface IERC721 {
    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _tokenId
    ) external;
}

contract Escrow {
    address public nftAddress;
    address payable public seller;
    address public inspector; //检察员
    address public lender; //贷方

    constructor(
        address _nftAddress,
        address payable _seller,
        address _inspector,
        address _lender
    ) {
        nftAddress = _nftAddress;
        seller = _seller;
        inspector = _inspector;
        lender = _lender;
    }

    function list(uint256 _nftID) public {
        IERC721(nftAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _nftID);
    }
}
```

this is my RealEstate.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract RealEstate is ERC721URIStorage {
    uint256 private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("Real Estate", "Real") {}

    function awardItem(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIds++;
        _mint(msg.sender, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenURI);

        return tokenId;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tokenIds;
    }
}
```

then  this is my test.js

```
const { expect, assert } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

const tokens = (n) => {
  return ethers.utils.parseUnits(n.toString(), "ether");
};

describe("Escrow", function () {
  let buyer, seller, lender, inspector;
  let realEstate, escrow;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    [buyer, seller, inspector, lender] = await ethers.getSigners();
    // const buyer = signers[0];
    // const seller = signers[1];
    const RealEstate = await ethers.getContractFactory("RealEstate");
    realEstate = await RealEstate.deploy();

    let transaction = await realEstate
      .connect(seller)
      .awardItem(
        "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUsuRJyRUmeHzZxes5FRMkc4mjx35HbaTzHzzWoiRdT5G"
      );

    const receipt = await transaction.wait();
    // 检查事务状态
    if (receipt.status === 1) {
      console.log("AwardItem transaction successful");
    } else {
      console.error("AwardItem transaction failed");
    }

    const Escrow = await ethers.getContractFactory("Escrow");
    escrow = await Escrow.deploy(
      realEstate.target,
      seller.address,
      inspector.address,
      lender.address
    );

    transaction = await realEstate.connect(seller).approve(escrow.target, 1);
    await transaction.wait();
    // console.log("Total Supply After Approve:", await realEstate.totalSupply());

    // transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).list(1);
    // await transaction.wait();
  });

  describe("Deploy!!", function () {
    it("return nftAddress", async function () {
      const result = await escrow.nftAddress();
      assert.equal(result, realEstate.target);
    });
    it("return sellerAddress", async function () {
      assert.equal(await escrow.seller(), seller.address);
    });
    it("return inspectorAddress", async function () {
      assert(await escrow.inspector(), inspector.address);
    });
    it("return lenderAddress", async function () {
      assert(await escrow.lender(), lender.address);
    });
    it("check tokenId", async function () {
      const id = await realEstate.totalSupply();
      console.log(id);
    });
  });

  //   describe("Listing", function () {
  //     it("Updates ownership", async function () {
  //       const owner = await realEstate.ownerOf(1);
  //       console.log(owner);
  //     });
  //   });
});
```

but error

```
yarn hardhat test
yarn run v1.22.21
warning package.json: No license field
$ D:\blockchain\hh-fcc\hotelRoom\node_modules\.bin\hardhat test


  Escrow
    Deploy!!
AwardItem transaction successful
Total Supply After AwardItem: 1
      1) "before each" hook for "return nftAddress"


  0 passing (3s)
  1 failing

  1) Escrow
       "before each" hook for "return nftAddress":
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'ERC721NonexistentToken(1)'
    at RealEstate._requireOwned (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol:451)
```

I encountered a problem when learning nft,please help me .thanks very much.When I call the totalSupply function, the return result is 1, which proves that I was successful in awardItem(). But I keep getting errors and I can’t figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

try adding tokenId to 0 instead of just 1.

like this

```
 describe("Listing", function () {
    it("Updates ownership", async function () {
      const owner = await realEstate.ownerOf(0);
     console.log(owner);
    });
  });
```

Also modify the approval arguments and list arguments as well.